# cycle class as Chern class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety and $Z \subset X$ a codimension $p$ closed algebraic subvariety. Then one can define the class of $Z$ in singular cohomology

$[Z] \in H^{2p}(X, \mathbb{Q})$

as follows: one has $H^{2p}(X, \mathbb{Q})=Hom(H^{2n-p}(X, \mathbb{Q}), \mathbb{Q})$ by Poincaré duality and we define $[Z]$ to be the class corresponding to the linear map
$$
\alpha \mapsto \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^{n-p}} \int_{\tilde{Z}} \iota^\ast(\alpha)
$$ 
where $\iota: \tilde{Z} \hookrightarrow X$ is a desingularization of $Z$.

I have read that it follows from the Riemann-Roch theorem that 
$$
[Z]=(2\pi i)^p \frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!} c_p(\mathcal{O}_Z) 
$$ but I cannot see why. Can anybody help?

Comment: I am afraid that I do not see how $[Z]$, defined with those funny factors of $\sqrt{-1}$ and $\pi$, can possibly be an element of $H^{2p}(X,\mathbb{Q})$, i.e., with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients.

Comment: I thought these "funny factors", as you call them, were there precisely to guarantee that it is a rational element!

Comment: One always have $[Z] = ch_p(O_Z)$ (the $p$-the coefficient of the Chern character), and in fact you don't need to resolve the singularities. Expressing it in terms of Chern classes and taking into account that $ch_i(O_Z) = c_i(O_Z) = 0$ for $0 < i < p$, one can prove the formula you want, but without the "funny factors"!

Comment: Thanks Sasha. Could you explain by $[Z]=ch_p(\mathcal{O}_Z)$?

Comment: This is Grothendieck--Riemann--Roch.

Answer (score 4):

You can use formula (16) of Grothendieck, *Theorie de classes de Chern*, and then map everything from Chow to singular cohomology. I'm sure there are other references, but I'm away from any books right now.

<strike>(Define $2\pi i =1$ for now!)</strike> To be  bit less facetious, for various reasons some people like to take the image of the cycle class map in $H^{2p}(X,\mathbb{Z}(-p)) = H^{2p}(X,(2\pi i)^{-p}\mathbb{Z})$. In which case, your formulas seem fine as written.